# Why is the timer clock doubled when APB Prescaler is not 1 in STM32?

Tags: arm, stm32, microcontroller

While trying to understand the timer work, I wondered why the APB's peripheral clock was not followed and used by multiplying double.

Is this a phenomenon caused by a structural problem? Or is it a part that is handled automatically for convenience?

Can you tell me the answer and associated STMicroelectronics document for reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timer clock is able to be set higher than the APB clock to allow power saving by reducing APB frequency while still achieving high timer resolution.

The details are in the reference manual.  For STM32F427-439 pay attention to the TIMPRE bit in the RCC_DCKCFGR register, and see figure 16 "clock tree" in manual RM0090.

Comment: I checked figure 16 in document RM0090. Is the reason the "if (APBx presc = 1x1 else x2" block exists because of power savings?

Comment: Yes, turning down the APB clock reduces the power usage of many peripherals, UART, SPI, I2C as well as the timer, but the application may require the timer resolution to be as high as possible.  But note this figure only applies to STM32F427/STM32F437/STM32F429/STM32F439.  You have to check the appropriate manual depending on the part you are using, which you didn't tell us.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Although I am testing with STM32F405VG, STM32F407ZE chips,
I think it is valid because only the subtype number is different from the chips you talked about.

Comment: Can you find documentation that describes that power saving?

Comment: The F405-F417 doesn't have the TIMPRE option.  F405-F417 is equivalent to F427-F429 with TIMPRE set to zero. In that case you need figure 21 in the same manual.

Comment: You can find the power consumption figures in the datasheet (not reference manual) but they are a bit theoretical.  For a real project you need to measure power consumption with hardware.